Я(,) по большей части(,) являюсь
Нужны запятые?
Я(,) по большей части(,) являюсь спокойным Котом.


Я, по большей части, являюсь спокойным Котом.

Запятые можно поставить (авторское решение), хотя отсутствие обособления считается основной формой письма. Здесь наречное выражение  по большей части важно для понимания смысла высказывания. Кроме того, позиция наречия между подлежащим и сказуемым способствует обособлению.
Мой брат, по большей части, предпочитал более деятельную роль кучера. В. Короленко, Парадокс.
Справочник по пунктуации

Сравнить (при наличии однородных сказуемых):

Я по большей части являюсь спокОйным Котом, // но иногда могу и разозлИться.
Здесь другая я расстановка логических ударений.
